# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not present for localhost

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I'm using the Instagram api and have successfully retrieved an access_token, along with using HTML5 geolocation to retrieve a user's location. This data is then used to construct the string to access the instagram endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search" + coordsquery + "&access_token=" + access
```

I have set my redirect uri from Instagram as `http://localhost/explorer` and my request for `access_token` in my application is `var redirect = "http://localhost/explorer";`

However I still get the error. I read that Chrome has a bug or something with localhost and making calls like this so I tried in firefox. Same deal.

I also read somewhere about appending `?callback=?` to the GET request url. Also no dice.

Comment: You have 2 errors: Cross-domain problems (http to https communication) and you are forgetting a `?` after `search`. The url should be `"//api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?" + coordsquery + "&access_token=" + access`, as far as syntax goes.

Comment: As to the cross-domain issue, can you possibly expound a bit? I don't understand really the difference between http and https besides the additional letter and something about increased security.

As for the second issue, I'd actually incorporated the leading "?" within `coordsquery`

Comment: https uses ssl to send and receive data. It's an encrypted exclusive connection between you and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what was wrong with my original:

```
$.get(querystring, function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

but I ended up trying this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: querystring, 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and it worked just fine.

If someone could possibly explain why the second approach worked where the first failed I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: the `jsonp` (JSON with padding) explains it all